# StripLine doesn't work properly if I zoom the chart

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, mschart

The StripLine works properly before I zoom like the below..:

[image: full chart image]

```
        var strip = new StripLine();
        strip.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
        strip.Interval = chart1.Series[0].Points.Count / 4;
        strip.StripWidth = chart1.Series[0].Points.Count / 8;
        strip.IntervalOffset = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(strip);
```

..but when I zoom a part of this chart the background is just covered all by the stripline color regardless of where I zoom or scroll like this:

[image]

I want to see only the part covered even when I zoom in.

What's the problem and how can I make this work?

Comment: Actually not all the background is covered. There is an issue with the value types used. Striplines need axis values, not point counts. This makes a difference as your data start at x=someHighNumber. -  Try this: `DataPoint dp1 = chart1.Series[0].Points[0];
DataPoint dp2 = chart1.Series[0].Points.Last();

double v1 = dp1.XValue;
double v2 = dp2.XValue;
double dd = v2 - v1;

strip.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
strip.Interval = dd / 4;
strip.StripWidth = dd / 8;` - This should take care of the size of the Striplines ie the Intervall...

Comment: - You may or may not want to also tweak the IntervalOffset. This depends on your purpose: Should they stick to the background? Then leaving the IOffset at 0 will do. Or should they move with the zoomed area? Then you need to calculate the new position, maybe like so: `private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines[0].IntervalOffset = 
            chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue - e.NewPosition;
}`

Comment: I have taken the liberty to edit your post a little and have closed it after adding an update an older answer of mine. The two comments above should be your start however.. - The duplicate uses the x-xime minimum and -maximum the calculate the axis size, which is better than the 1st and lst points, imo..